# OpenCV Bundle Adjuster fails

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, computer-vision

**Background:**
I am trying to stitch 5 images into a full spherical 360x180 panorama. The images are taken with a fisheye lens (hfov ~ 100). I defished those images and used openCV 3.1's stitching routine to stitch these images.

**Problem:**
When I stitch 2, 3 or 4 images, the resultant panorama is fine. But as I try to stitch all 5 images, openCV's bundle adjuster code fails to converge to a minimum error. The rms error gets very large. I understand Levenberg Marquardt algorithm and have seen the BA code but its very complicated for me(as I'm a newbie)

**Question:**
What changes shall I make in bundle adjuster to get a 360x180 full view spherical panorama?

Following image contains some parameters for BA
[image]

The resulting panorama should be seamless just like [this](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse576/05sp/projects/proj3/artifacts/yongjoon/rick_bundle.jpg) or [this](https://cdn2.ps1.photosynth.net/pano/c01001200-AFQeOxg8oyw/thumbnail_files/thumb.jpg). It looks like a normal image but when viewed with a 3d viewer such as ptgui or VR player, there would not be any misalignment at the ends. Such image can be wrapped to inside of a sphere and can be viewed from center.

Comment: is the problem that the last image would be matched to both sides? Could you try to cut the last image in 2 halfs?

Comment: Yes that is also a problem. Both sides should be aligned for a seamless 360 effect. 

What do you mean by cutting last image in two halves?

Comment: how should the result look like? an imagräe typically is rectangular and has a start and an end in each direction

Comment: I have added some images. The resultant image will be rectangular image. However by using 3rd party VR softwares, such images can be mapped inside a sphere.

Comment: can you add 4 working and 5th non-working input images?

Comment: I'm really sorry the images are proprietary so I cant share here.